# Remove useless zero after number

Tags: magento-1.9, php, price

we are using this code for displaying shipping charges in magento site :

```
<?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
<?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>

<?php echo "Selling Price + " . $_excl . " Delivery "; ?>
```

where `$_excl` will return the value.

its displaying results as 10.00, 20.00...etc.

I want to **remove .00** from "10.00" & display only 10.

I checked [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903171/removing-all-decimals-in-php) & [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531679/remove-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals-in-php)

I tried below codes :

```
echo "Selling Price + " . number_format($_excl, 0) . " Delivery ";
echo "Selling Price + " . (int)$_excl . " Delivery ";
echo "Selling Price + " . ($_excl + 0) . " Delivery ";
echo "Selling Price + " . (int)$_excl . " Delivery "  .  "\n";
echo "Selling Price + " . number_format($_excl,0) . " Delivery "  .  "\n";  
echo "Selling Price + " . round($_excl,0) . " Delivery "  .  "\n";
echo "Selling Price + " . intval($_excl,0) . " Delivery "  .  "\n";
echo "Selling Price + " . ($_excl + 0) . " Delivery ";
echo "Selling Price + " . round($_excl,0) . " Delivery ";
echo "Selling Price + " . round($_excl) . " Delivery ";
echo "Selling Price + " . $_excl + 0 . " Delivery ";
```

most of above code gave this as output: `Selling Price + 0 Delivery`, means result in zero, correct values did display as 10,  20...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  function

`number_format($_excl, 0, '.', '');`

Comment: its displaying `Selling Price + Delivery` , but values are not displaying

Comment: i tested this code it is working perfectly did this include the $ with it

Comment: i used your code like this : `echo "Selling Price + " . number_format($_excl, 2, '.', '') . " Delivery ";`

Comment: i updated 2 more lines of code in question, please check.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right path. I got an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
echo "Selling Price + " . str_replace('.00','',$_excl) . " Delivery ";
```

Comment: Really helpful to me